# ARIMA d Parameter and Explicit Differencing

Tags: arima

Can I use only d parameter for ARIMA instead of applying differencing to data before training and applying inverse transform to forecasts in order to get them into original scale? Do libraries like statsmodels do this implicitly?

Comment: coming from your [other post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/87152/ar-coefficients-are-not-stationary) the python lib referenced indeed uses the $d$ parameter to mean the step of differencing. So the answer to this question would be yes, however choice of parameters is another matter for best fit

Comment: Yes, it is. I examined many examples. Some people show how applying differencing is useful in order to make timeseries stationary, then used only differencing parameter as input to statsmodels ARIMA, and some people not use this parameter instead they define differencing and its inverse as functions. I just wonder both methods are equal or is there a better way. Thanks.